Matplotlib widget in VS Code - black text is illegible on dark background color
I've been switching from using Jupyter in-browser to using Jupyter within VS Code. In trying to setup the environment, I followed the steps outlined in this forum to achieve a dark background when plotting using the %matplotlib widget command
I'm working in WSL, so the path I used was not the same as mentioned in the forum linked above. Specifically, I changed background:white to background:transparent in /home/<username>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.3.1-linux-x64/dist/webviews/webview-side/ipywidgetsRenderer/ipywidgetsRenderer.js
After implementing this, the following code:
#python 3.8.10
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
plt.show()

Produces:
current appearance
The issue I have is that the text on the now transparent background above and below the graph is black. if you squint, you can see "Figure 1" above the graph and the coordinates of the cursor location below the graph. I don't see any option for text color in ipywidgetsRenderer.js, and I'm not sure where to look. I don't know if python itself via matplotlib controls this, or if it's a setting in VS Code (I'm a physics graduate student using python for data analysis, and I'm not familiar with how all these backends(?) work).
So I'm hoping to find a file that controls the color of this text, so that I can change it to white. If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate your suggestions.
reference: Make Matplotlib widget background color match dark theme in Visual Studio Code

For those not really needing this quite right now or not wishing to face messing with VSCode for every update...I wonder if it is just a matter of the underlying tech not updating yet to the newer supporting stuff for Jupyter because in JupyterLab 4.1.6 and Jupyter Notebook Version 7.1.2 with the Dark theme, the text is white for the Figure 1 label above and for the coordinates. Even with or without the addition of plt.style.use('dark_background') in the example code. (I will note that for Jupyter Notebook Version 7.1.2, I had to run it a second time to get the style ....

 from dark_background respected. (The main part of the plot background stayed white on first pass.) That's a bit weird but second time the cell is run, it works.)

Are you saying this can be resolved by updating jupyter?

Not necessarily because I'm not sure how you have VSCode connected to Jupyter. I'm suggesting when the underlying pieces are updated to use more current Jupyter tech, the issue may go away. The example here is actually using Jupyter and so it should ultimately go away. Not sure though if you used that way to integrate your VSCode with Jupyter. Plus, I thought I saw things had changed recently that VSCode included Jupyter notebook support itself because folks were complaining they didn't want that option.

I'm more trying to caution any other folks with needs maybe less pressing than you that any fix that comes up may be fragile. That path to ipywidgetsRenderer.js doesn't look typical to me for Jupyter, and so I would imagine that whatever controls how.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.3.1-linux-x64 gets made has to be updated by whoever is behind developing it (MS?) and then it will work without any modifications. Given it works in  the most current Jupyter, it may eventually be fixed to work as you expect. Until then, updating VSCode may undo your attempts to address it.
